# Convergence of the sequence $ a_{n}=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}-\int_{1}^{n} \frac{1}{x} d x$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let
$$
a_{n}=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}-\int_{1}^{n} \frac{1}{x} d x$$
for all $n \in \mathbb{N} .$ Show that $\left(a_{n}\right)$ converges.

Actually $
a_{n}=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}$ is the Reimann upper sum of $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ on the interval $[1,n]$ relative to a partition such that  each subinterval of unit length, But I couldn't prove the convergence.

Can we use the fact
$\ln (n+1) \leq 1+\frac{1}{2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n} \leq 1+\ln n$

Comment: Does it converge to 1 ?

Comment: I asked so because $ 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} +....$ converges to 1.

Comment: I think so, just because I am 15 and I am just trying a hand at something I can't really do...

Comment: Or maybe the series converges to 0?

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}$ is divergent.

Comment: Oh... ok..... I am a child, you see

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rearrange the integral as a telescopic sum and use the fact that $\ln (1+x) = x+\mathcal O(x^2)$:
$$\begin{split}
\left (\sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1 k\right) -\int_1^n\frac{dx}x &= 1 + \left (\sum_{k=2}^n \frac 1 k\right)-\ln n\\
&= 1 + \sum_{k=2}^n \left(\frac 1 k -\ln k +\ln (k-1)  \right)\\
&= 1 + \sum_{k=2}^n \left(\frac 1 k +\ln \left(1 - \frac 1 k \right)  \right)\\
&= 1 + \sum_{k=2}^n \mathcal O \left(\frac 1 {k^2} \right)\\
\end{split}$$
The latter sum converges.

Comment: What does the latter sum converge to?

Comment: It doesn't really matter as the question was to prove the convergence. But I guess it converges to $\gamma - 1$.

Comment: cool. Was just curious